# How to constantly set specific values of an array to null in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

After a method in my program a certain element of an array is declared null in the form of:

```
 elementsArr[y][x] = null;
```

However after this I need the element being made null to be added to a list of elements to constantly be set null. I have considered this and come up with the following algorithm, please tell me if I am overcomplicating this or on the right track.

```
    public void killList(int x, int y){

    int kill [] = new int [50];
    int count =0;

    kill[count] = x;
    kill[count+1] =y;

    for(int i =0; i<=kill.length;i++)
    {
        elementsArr[i][i+1] = null;
    }

    count++;
}
```

Comment: A primitive element of an array can't be set to null.

Comment: Your code is equivalent to:
public void killList(int unsed_x, int unused_y) {
  for( int i = 0; i <= 50; i++ )
    elementsArr[i][i+1] = null;
}
thus if elementsArr is a non-primitive two dimensional arry (element types may be null) at least 50x51 in size the elements directly above the diagonal (indices (0,1), (1,2), ...) are set to null.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your current implementation - you can only have a kill list of 25 entries, and your loop won't kill the right entries because you are iterating through every entry in the kill array, not every other one. It will null entries at (x1, y1), (y1, x2), (x2, y2) etc.

The best way to do this is create a coordinate object like this:

```
class Coordinate {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Then store a set of these, and iterate through them. The set is unbounded so this will support a huge kill list.